# Using jQuery to define and add a variable for an SVG function isn't working

Tags: jquery, variables, dom, svg, this

I have an SVG map with many grouped regions, each with their own unique ID. And then labels with unique matching classes So for example (simplified) ...

```
<svg>

  <g id="regions">
    <g id="region1">
      <path></path>
      <path></path>
    </g>
    <g id="region2">
      <path></path>
      <path></path>
    </g>
  </g>

  <g id="labels">
    <g class="region1" onmouseover="hoverOn()" onmouseout="hoverOff()">
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
  </g>
  <g class="region2" onmouseover="hoverOn()" onmouseout="hoverOff()">
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
  </g>
 </g> 

</svg>
```

And then I want to write a jQuery script (simplified so that I don't have to write a unique one for every single region. but I'm having trouble defining and using a variable. I want to do something like this:

```
<script>
  function hoverOn(){
    var frack = this.getAttribute('class');
    $('svg g#' + frack).attr('class', 'hover');
  }
  function hoverOff(){
    var frack = this.getAttribute('class');
    $('svg g#' + frack).attr('class', '');
  }
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. If I define the variable as an actual region name it works. Like this:

```
<script>
  function hoverOn(){
    var frack = 'region1';
    $('svg g#' + frack).attr('class', 'hover');
  }
  function hoverOff(){
    var frack = 'region1';
    $('svg g#' + frack).attr('class', '');
  }
</script>
```

Then hovering any labels adds hover class to:

```
<g id="region1">
```

so it reads:

```
<g id="region1" class="hover">
```

So I know it's just the variable problem. I know the SVG DOM is different, but I thought .getAttribute('class') could be used in place of .className ... is it "this" that doesn't work?

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean. Please elaborate.  Also, please provide an [MCVE].

Comment: Also, shouldn't `this.getAttribute('class')` be `this.getAttribute('id')`?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response ...

Comment: Doesn't work means it fails to add the class of .hover to the matching region. It actually fails to do anything at all. And I thought I did provide code. Is there more than you need? I don't want to give the URL because in order to do so I'd have to give login info to my client's staging site.

Comment: I'm trying to get the class of the label hovered, so that I can add a .hover class to the region with a matching ID. So for example, hover the label with class .asia and add a class of .hover to the region with ID of #asia. Make sense? So, that's why I'm using "this.getAttribute('class')"

Comment: Code is good. But posting a functioning example, so others don't have to do work to see your problem in action, is more likely to get you an answer.

Comment: Thank you. I've looked at thousands of stack overflow questions over the years but have never posted one myself. I'll try to get better at it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have guessed, the problem is with this line:

```
var frack = this.getAttribute('class');
```

In the event handler (`hoverOn()`), the value of `this` is not the element you are hovering over.  If you use `console.log()` to log it to the browser console, you'll see it is actually the browser `Window` object.

What you should be doing, to get the target element, is to pass `this` in your `onmouseover` attribute. Then get it as a parameter in your `hoverOn` function.

```
<g class="region1" onmouseover="hoverOn(this)" ...>

function hoverOn(elem) {
  var frack = elem.getAttribute('class');
  ...
}
```

See working demo below:

```js
function hoverOn(elem) {
  var frack = elem.getAttribute('class');
  $('svg g#' + frack).attr('class', 'hover');
}

function hoverOff(elem) {
  var frack = elem.getAttribute('class');
  $('svg g#' + frack).attr('class', '');
}
```

```css
.hover {
  fill:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>

  <g id="regions">
    <g id="region1">
      <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50"/>
    </g>
    <g id="region2">
      <circle cx="225" cy="75" r="50"/>
    </g>
  </g>

  <g id="labels">
    <g class="region1" onmouseover="hoverOn(this)" onmouseout="hoverOff(this)">
      <rect x="25" y="125" width="100" height="25" fill="green"/>
    </g>
    <g class="region2" onmouseover="hoverOn(this)" onmouseout="hoverOff(this)">
      <rect x="175" y="125" width="100" height="25" fill="green"/>
    </g>
  </g> 

</svg>
```

One last point. Using `onxxx` attributes is not the recommended way of doing things these days.  Generally it is preferabl to use `addEventListener()` to register event handlers.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseover

Or, if you are using jQuery, use jQuery's utility functions (eg. `on()`, `mouseover()`, etc) to do it.

Comment: I appreciate very much both the solution and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Also, just FYI but based on the above answer ... I figured out how to reverse it too, so that hovering over a region would light up the corresponding label as well.

The final code looks something like this:

```
    function hoverRegionOn(labelElem) {
      var labelName = labelElem.getAttribute('class');
      $('svg g#' + labelName).attr('class', 'hover');
    }
    function hoverRegionOff(labelElem) {
      var labelName = labelElem.getAttribute('class');
      $('svg g#' + labelName).attr('class', '');
    }
    function hoverLabelOn(regionElem) {
      var regionName = regionElem.getAttribute('id');
      $('svg g.' + regionName).attr('class', 'hover');
    }
    function hoverLabelOff(regionElem) {
      var regionName = regionElem.getAttribute('id');
      $('svg #labels g.hover').attr('class', regionName);
    }
```